# Understanding which object is owned by which thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Trying to access WPF Controls from another thread is leading into *'System.InvalidOperationException'* (cross thread access violation).
The Description of the exception says, that *the accessed object is not owned by the calling thread*.

The following code shows that the *'System.InvalidOperationException'* is not thrown when the second thread is accessing an non WPF-Control Object. But Why ?

How can I identify which Object is owned by which thread to avoid this exception ?

```
namespace Threading {
    
    public class TestObject {
        public Object Data { get; set; }
    }
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        TestObject _toOwnedByUI;     
        TextBox _txtOwnedByUI;
        BackgroundWorker _bw;

        public MainWindow () {
            InitializeComponent ();
            _bw = new BackgroundWorker ();
            _txtOwnedByUI = OutputBox;
            _bw.DoWork += onBwDoWork;
        }

        private void Button_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            // initvalues from UI-Thread
            _toOwnedByUI = new TestObject () { Data = "UI Thread INIT" };
            _txtOwnedByUI.Text = "UI Thread INIT";
            // Start Second Thread
            _bw.RunWorkerAsync ();
        }

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------         
        private void onBwDoWork(Object Sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            // Change Values of testobjects by Second Thread
            _toOwnedByUI.Data = "Changed by BW-Thread";
            _txtOwnedByUI.Text = "Changed by BW-Thread";        // <----- throws System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid Thread
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only UI objects have thread affinity, objects of your TestObject class can be accessed from any thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associating objects with threads is a `WPF` concept - it is **NOT** something that applies to all objects.

Every `WPF` object is derived from `DispatcherObject` which associates itself with the dispatcher of the current thread.

Later on, all operations on this objects are manually protected from cross thread calls with a call to `VerifyAccess()` which throws exception if the calling thread is different than the "owner" thread.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherObject.cs,85082c8bba6e8038

For example, you can accomplish same behavior in your `TestObject` class by deriving from the `DispatcherObject` and protecting the `Data` property getter and setter with `VerifyAccess()`.

At the end, you assumption that `TestObject _tbOwnedByUI` is owned by UI thread is wrong, there is no such concept/behavior for objects by default. That pretty much answers the questions.